# Multi-page jQuery form not submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Here is the jQuery code

```
$("#register-form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).validate({
    rules: {
        name: "required",
        address: "required",
        phone: "required",
        landmark: "required",
        pincode: "required",
        city: "required",
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: "Please enter your name",
        address: "Please enter your address",
        phone: "Please enter your phone",
        landmark: "Please enter your landmark",
        pincode: "Please enter your pincode",
        city: "Please enter your city",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        //form.submit();
        //alert("Do some stuff...");
        $("#step1").hide();
        //$('#step1img').css('opacity','0.5');
        //$('#step2img').css('opacity','1');
        $("#step2").show();

        //submit via ajax
        return false;
    }
});
// });

$("#back").click(function () {
    $("#step1").show();
    $("#step2").hide();
});

function submitform() {
    document.getElementById('#register-form').submit();
}
```

this is my fiddle , http://jsfiddle.net/bd4T2/ i have tried multipage form , using jquery validation js , but form is not submitting

Comment: go to the page in a chrome browser, then right click on the page`->inspect element`, there should be a red cross/error icon in the bottom right of the opening panel, click on it and any errors will show up, then share those errors here

Comment: okay, when I run this in the fiddle I get two errors, they read; `Uncaught ReferenceError: isNumber is not defined` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: submitform is not defined`

Comment: i need to submit form , any idea ,

Answer (score 0):

okay, I copied the code out of the fiddle (which wasn't working and did not include the jquery library) and i found the error in the submitform function, you've got a hash in front of the form id when using the dom to find the form:

```
function submitform() {
    document.getElementById('#register-form').submit(); //<-- '#register-form'
}
//this is not going to work, you were looking to use jquery here
document.getElementById('#register-form').submit();
```

will not work, because there's no `#` in the form id, so it should read like this;

```
function submitform() {
   $('#register-form').submit();
}
```

Comment: submitform is not defined err

Comment: yes, that is the error you got before, let me just clarify my answer

Comment: replace your submitform function with mine